# MinGW GCC Not Recognizing MEMSTATUSEX?

Tags: c, api, winapi, gcc, mingw

I am using MinGW GCC compiler on Windows 7.  I am trying to compile source that contains the following code:

```
MEMORYSTATUSEX mem_stat;
mem_stat.dwLength = sizeof(memstat);
BOOL success = GlobalMemoryStatusEx(mem_stat);
ram_ptr = &(mem_stat->ullAvailPhys);
```

As I'm sure you can guess, this code simply gets the available memory using the MEMORYSTATUSEX struct returned by GlobalMemoryStatusEx.

When I try to compile, I get this error:

```
error: unknown type name 'MEMORYSTATUSEX'
```

I looked in winbase.h (in the MinGW installation include folder) and guess what I found?

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500)
typedef struct _MEMORYSTATUSEX {
    DWORD dwLength;
    DWORD dwMemoryLoad;
    DWORDLONG ullTotalPhys;
    DWORDLONG ullAvailPhys;
    DWORDLONG ullTotalPageFile;
    DWORDLONG ullAvailPageFile;
    DWORDLONG ullTotalVirtual;
    DWORDLONG ullAvailVirtual;
    DWORDLONG ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
} MEMORYSTATUSEX,*LPMEMORYSTATUSEX;
#endif
```

So it's there.  I'm guessing this has something to do with the precompiler if/endif, but I don't how to fix that....

Also what's even more bizzare is that if I use the MEMORYSTATUS struct instead, it works fine.

According to the MS docs, both have the same minimum client version requirement:

MEMORYSTATUSEX:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

MEMORYSTATUS:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366772%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Is there some compiler flag I need to set?  Or does anyone have any other solutions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You must have noticed the #if for _WIN32_WINNT right above it.  What did you set it to?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I didn't set it to anything...

Comment: Oh ok.  I defined it and that stopped it.  Thank you.

Comment: You should put how you `defined it` in an answer to your own question. So it goes out of the unanswered list.

Comment: Fair enough.  I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to define _WIN32_WINNT yourself either as a compiler flag or definition statement in one of your header/source files for this particular function to work properly.

Adding the `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500` will allow the code to compile normally.

Answer (score 3):

Before including Windows.h, add :

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
```

The header file windef.h says :

```
/*
 * If you need Win32 API features newer the Win95 and WinNT then you must
 * define WINVER before including windows.h or any other method of including
 * the windef.h header.
 */
```

and then compile with the -std=c++11 flag like :

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -c <yourFile>.cpp -o <yourFile>.o
```