# undeclared function RegGetValue MinGW C compiler

Tags: c, winapi, registry, mingw

I am trying to compile a C program using MinGW on Windows 7 (64-bit). The code is given below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void readRegDwordValue() {

    HKEY hKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    char const *subKey = "Software\\Metpl\\My Program";
    char const *pValue = "MJP_XXX";
    uint32_t flags = RRF_RT_REG_DWORD;
    int *pvData = NULL;

    int64_t result = RegGetValue(hKey, &subKey, pValue, flags, NULL, pvData, sizeof(DWORD));

    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Error getting value. Code: ");
        printf("%" PRId64 "\n", result);
    } else {
        printf("Value data: ");
        printf("%" PRId32 "\n", *(int32_t*)pvData);
    }
}

int main() {
    readRegDwordValue();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
    gcc -O3 -Wall -c -o readReg.o readReg.c

readReg.c: In function 'readRegDwordValue':
readReg.c:13:22: warning: implicit declaration of function 'RegGetValue'; did you mean 'RegSetValue'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
13 |     int64_t result = RegGetValue(hKey, &subKey, pValue, flags, NULL, pvData, sizeof(DWORD));
    |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
    |                      RegSetValue
```

I have included `windows.h` which includes `winreg.h` that contains the definition of the `RegGetvalue` function. Why is the compiler not able to find it? Also, since it is suggesting that I meant `RegSetValue`, does it mean it is able to find this one? !!

The linker gives the following error:

```
gcc readReg.o -o readReg.exe -L -liphlpapi -ladvapi32

d:/__sdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: readReg.o:readReg.c:(.text+0x45):
undefined reference to `RegGetValue'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing here? I have been pulling my hair over this for over 8 hours now and not able to understand where I am making the mistake. I have not been able to find much relevant discussion online on this either.

Desperately request some input on this so that I can move forward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know about mingw headers, but technically, RegGetValue doesn't exist, there's only RegGetValueA (ansi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluea) or RegGetValueW (unicode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluew). If you don't want to rip your hair programming with Windows I suggest you use Visual Studio and the Windows SDK which are official headers for Windows programming.

Comment: RegGetValue does exist, it is a macro which is replaced by the correct function depending on the UNICODE compilation or not.

Comment: @CGi03 I had already tried `RegGetValueA` but got the same warnings.

Comment: I tested your code on two versions of MinGW-w64, the function is recognized. She doesn't have it on MinGW 5.1
(You will see later, but parameters 2 and 7 are not correct).

Comment: @CGi03 thanks for pointing me to MinGW-w64. I used the 32-bit version of it and it works perfectly. This version does break some of the portable programs I have written. So, now I have to maintain both versions.

Comment: @SimonMourier `RegGetValue` does exist. Please refer the article [Use Modern C++ to Access the Windows Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/c-use-modern-c-to-access-the-windows-registry) to understand how RegGetValue API simplifies the workflow of the various registry functions.

Comment: @CGi03 It turned out that both the OSDN minGW version (the one I have been using) and the MinGW-w64 versions (which I used, as per your suggestion) work. The reason the OSDN version threw an `undefined reference` warning was that their `RegGetValue` function was #defined for `>= _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA` version. They have not provided (at least I am unable to find it) a way of setting the `_WIN32_WINNT` flag. I found a way to override this flag by placing `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601` before #including `windows.h`. Refer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/26383424/3958207](SO article)

Comment: For MinGW-w64 version, you can edit the `_WIN32_WINNT` flag in `_mingw.h` file, it you don't want to add it in your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! All the hair-pulling bore fruit. And, all the peripheral learning along the journey now seems exhilarating. Following is what works with MinGW-w64 (32-bit):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

char buffer[1024]; // Based on need. This is the max that I need.
DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);

DWORD readRegDwordValue(HKEY hKey, char const *subKey, char const *pValue) {
    long unsigned int *p = NULL;
    int64_t result = RegGetValue(hKey, subKey, pValue, RRF_RT_REG_DWORD, p, &buffer, &bufferSize);

    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        return 4294967295; // max unsigned int.
    }

    return ((DWORD *)buffer)[0]; // return the first element of the buffer.
}

char * readStringValue(HKEY hKey, char const *subKey, char const *pValue) {
    long unsigned int *p = NULL;
    int64_t result = RegGetValue(hKey, subKey, pValue, RRF_RT_REG_SZ, p, &buffer, &bufferSize);

    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        return "Error";
    }

    return (char *)buffer;
}

int main() {
    char *string = readStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Metpl\\My Program", "companyName");
    printf("string:%s%s%d%s \n", string, " (length = ", strlen(string), ")");

    DWORD integerValue = readRegDwordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Metpl\\My Program", "sampleInteger");
    printf("integer:(%lu%s\n", integerValue, ")");

    return 0;
}
```

I have tested this code and it gives correct results. Since I only need to get the correct result or an error, I have not added additional error-checking in the code.

Thanks, @CGio3, for pointing me to MinGW-w64. I have made many Portable C programs and a few Windows programs with the version I have and got too comfortable with it, I guess. Anyway, lesson learnt.

Hope this helps someone who has been struggling with the subject.